# Alternative to Switch statement for grouping results- MS Access

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a table that keeps track of the letters we send to our customers. We are also keeping track of the letter status in this table, and specifically, we want to know how many people who received a letter agreed to be contacted again.

This part is easy, but now I have been asked to group the results by pre-specified weeks (i.e. Week 1, Week 2, etc). I have been using a switch statement for this purpose, but now that we are in the 20th or so week, MS Access is saying the query is too complex.

Here is my code - with the switch statement simplified for the sake of brevity. We actually have weeks 1-20 in the actual switch statement, and this is what is causing Access to not process the query.

```
SELECT Count([Letter Status].Patient_ID) AS CountOfPatient_ID, Switch([Date_Returned] Between #10/25/2011# And #10/31/2011#,"Week 1") AS Week
FROM [Letter Status]
WHERE ((([Letter Status].Letter_Status)="Agreed to be contacted"))
GROUP BY Switch([Date_Returned] Between #10/25/2011# And #10/31/2011#,"Week 1");
```

Since the switch statement isn't working, I was wondering if there was a more logical way for processing the results by Week. Our temporary solution involves me processing one week at a time, and adding the results to a separate table. However, I'm pretty sure this goes against db normalization, and if there is a better way to do it, I would like to learn.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group using [datepart](http://%5Benter%20link%20description%20here%5D%5B1%5D) instead.

E.g.,

```
GROUP BY datepart("ww", Date_Returned)
```

If the week numbers returned by Access don't match the numbers you need, just add or subtract an offset number as necessary.

Comment: Great idea, thanks. Since my Week 1 actually correlates with the Calendar Week 40- I am subtracting 39. This pretty much solves everything, except our most recent weeks (since we are starting over in 2012) are coming up as -38, -37, and -36). Would it be best to just create a look up table with the correlating values (i.e. -38 = Week 1), or would it be better to evaluate these in with an IIf statement? I'm leaning towards the look up table.

Comment: @Jerry what number is Access week 1 supposed to have in your numbering system?

Comment: I.e., do the week numbers reset each year, or do they just keep accumulating?

Comment: the weeks reset each year. Week 1 according to MS Access is actually my Week 15 (the first week in January). I just created a look up table and it seems to be working fine. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

if you used datediff using your first week as the base, something like

```
WeekNo = datediff("ww","1/7/2011",Date_Returned)
```

this will keep incrementing and you wont need to worry about the change of year.